# Android Permission, required="false", fail

Tags: android, permissions

My application provides the user with *optional* access to SMS and Phone calls. I have used:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
```

Google Play does not expose this application to devices that do not have cellular network access. It seems like the required = false parameter is failing to do its job.

Is this a bug? Is there something else that I can do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why are you putting the required parameter inside a permission?
The android:required param is used when you declare a feature, afaik...
For example:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

I think what you wanted to do is add `uses-feature` declarations with `android:required="false"`.

Use this table to update your manifest:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: because some uses-features cause google play to generate a uses permissions which affect filtering for some devices. emphasis on some.

Comment: @IncrediApp Thanks for sharing the link. That table has limited number of permission-feature mapping. What about the permissions in manifest which are not listed in the table in your link?

Comment: @LassiKinnunen you mean the opposite: some `uses-permisson`s are translated by google play to a corresponding `uses-feature` automatically, see the link provided in the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can see all the permissions in the permissions tab in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to use the property `android:required` in `<uses-permission` it only works for  `<uses-feature`, see the definition of

> **uses-feature** :  To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in
>    elements, rather than relying on Google Play to
>   "discover" the requirements in `<uses-permission>` elements. Then, if
>   you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a
>   `android:required="false"` attribute to the  declaration.

this is the list of permissions that imply hardware features:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features

Based on your  elements:

you probably need to add only :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```